# Got Hat Trick, at 199

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The description for Hat Trick is:

> hit the reputation cap on three different days

First of all, I'm not complaining :)

I received this hat (hard to say "earned") a couple of hours ago, without actually reaching 200 (yet).

[image]

Comment: I think that -1 may be the cause. Probably the system counts upvote and downvotes separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The down votes you cast are private, therefore they don't count - you have reached 200 rep.

> [image]

Neither does count the system, as it doesn't in case with the rep cap badges (Mortarboard, Epic, Legendary).

(what will I see after you get an up vote? I'll see that you've earned 201 rep :)

Comment: Makes sense! I'll have to test that 201 rep thing :)

Comment: Yes, this hat uses the same definition as the rep cap badges @janos.